# Splitting an ONNX DNN Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, onnx

*I'm trying to split **DNN Models** in order to execute part of the network on the **edge** and the rest on the **cloud**.* Because it has to be cross-platform and work with every framework I need to do it directly starting from an **ONNX** **model**.

I know how to generate an ONNX model starting from tensorflow/keras and how to run an ONNX model, but I realized that is really hard to work on the ONNX file, like visualizing it and modify it.

Is there someone that can help me understand how to split and ONNX model, or at least run part of an ONNX model (like from input to layer N and from layer N to the output)?

I'm starting from this situation:

```
# load MobileNetV2 model
model = MobileNetV2()

# Export the model
tf.saved_model.save(model, "saved_model")  

# export to .onnx
!python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model saved_model --output mobilenet_v2.onnx --opset 7

# open the saved ONNX Model
print("Import ONNX Model..")
onnx_model = onnx.load("mobilenet_v2.onnx")
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model, logging_level="WARN", auto_cast=True)
```

I tried to use **sclblonnx** but on models this big(although it's a small model) I can't really print the graph and when I list the inputs and outputs with  textlist_inputs/list_outputs I don't really get how ther are interconnected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From [Onnx PythonAPI specs](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/PythonAPIOverview.md#extracting-sub-model-with-inputs-outputs-tensor-names), you can split onnx model by specifying input name and output name of the tensors.

Comment: But how do we know the names without opening/visualizing the file ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you probably need to do is understand the underlining **graph** for the onnx model you have.

```
onnx_graph = onnx_model.graph
```

Will return the graph object.

After that, you need to understand where you want to separate this graph into two separate graphs (and so run two models).

You can plot the graph with Netron (this is what sclblonnx does) or you can try to look inside manually by looking at

```
onnx_graph_nodes = onnx_graph.node
```

Of course looking at the graph inputs(`onnx_graph.input`) and outputs (`onnx_graph.output`) is also important.

If you look at the "[merge](https://github.com/scailable/sclblonnx/blob/master/sclblonnx/merge.py)" file from sclblonnx you will see the syntax details for diving into a graph as well as a "split" function at may help you.